# Optimization - return first value in array that is smaller then cell value (for each row)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to create a new column in a dataframe, which contains (in each cell) the first value in an array that is smaller than the value in each corresponding cell from an already existing column. Here's a quick explanation of how this should work, there are 3 scenarios that I have identified:
1. Create and array `a` from 10 to 75 with a step of 5.
2a. If column `c1` has values 0 through 10 in a cell, the result in the new column should be `0` (I found this to be tricky without adding a zero to array `a`, which I'd rather not do). Column `c1` is always non-negative.
2b. If `c1` is 11 though 75, it should return the element of `a` that is immediately smaller than the cell value.
2c. If `c1` is greater than 75, it should return 75. (This is just an extension of 2b, really)

Here is my try - it does the job but I feel it's quite slow. I don't think I can use `np.argmax` or `np.argmin` because neither acomplishes points 2a/b/c above. Hopefully there's a faster solution out there.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
N = 10**6  #number of rows in df, change this to lower values for testing
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': np.random.randint(1,100,N)}) 

a = np.arange(10,80,5)

def first_lower(value, arr):
    if len(arr[arr < value]) > 0:
        return arr[arr < value][-1]  
    else:
        return 0

def do_stuff(input_df):
    df = input_df.copy()
    df['NewCol'] = df['c1'].apply(lambda x: first_lower(x, a))
    return df

%timeit do_stuff(df)
# 11.4 s ± 881 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to just include a much smaller dataframe (probably5-10 rowsA) with an expected output than a 1million row one.  Makes it simpler to validate results.

Comment: The problem is optimizing the execution speed so I used a big df. The function I implemented already does what is supposed to, and by changing `N` to a smaller value you can easily obtain a smaller dataframe

Comment: Does `a` get as big as `df` or this array is going to be small or not too big?

Comment: @jdehesa `a` is always small, less than 100 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @user3483203's but a bit more general:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
N = 20  # Just 20 for testing
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': np.random.randint(1,100,N)}) 
a = np.arange(10,80,5)
idx = np.searchsorted(a, df.c1)
newcol = a[idx - 1]
newcol[idx == 0] = 0
df['newcol'] = newcol
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    c1  newcol
0   52      50
1   93      75
2   15      10
3   72      70
4   61      60
5   21      20
6   83      75
7   87      75
8   75      70
9   75      70
10  88      75
11  24      20
12   3       0
13  22      20
14  53      50
15   2       0
16  88      75
17  30      25
18  38      35
19   2       0
```

Answer (score 3):

***Setup***

```
np.random.seed(1995)
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)})
a = np.arange(10,80,5)
```

***Option 1***
You can use `np.select`:

```
c1 = df.c1.isin(range(0, 11))
c2 = df.c1.isin(range(11,76))

r1 = 0
r2 = a[np.searchsorted(a, df.c1, side='left')-1]

np.select([c1, c2], [r1, r2], 75)
```

Output:

```
array([35, 75, 35, 50, 65, 25, 75, 50, 25, 65])
```

***Option 2***
Using `np.clip`:

```
s = np.clip(df.c1, 0, 75)
s[s.isin(range(11,75))] = a[np.searchsorted(a, df.c1)-1]
```

***Timings***:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': np.random.randint(1,100,10**6)})
%%timeit
c1 = df.c1.isin(range(0, 11))
c2 = df.c1.isin(range(11,76))
r1 = 0
r2 = a[np.searchsorted(a, df.c1, side='left')-1]    
np.select([c1, c2], [r1, r2], 75)

# 104 ms ± 214 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
s = np.clip(df.c1, 0, 75)
s[s.isin(range(11,75))] = a[np.searchsorted(a, df.c1)-1]

# 96 ms ± 1.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Upvoted this because it's really informative. Unfortunately, Option 2 return 75 for `c1 < 10` although it should return 0. Will look into it to see how it might be adjusted.